# Complex contour integral with sign function:$-i \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{{\rm sgn}(x)^2 ~x~ e^{i x}}{1+ax^2} dp$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to evaluate the integral:

$-i \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{{\rm sgn}(x)^2 ~x~ e^{i x}}{1+ax^2} dx$

with sgn$(x)$ the sign function and $a$ positive real. Naively applying the residue theorem and pushing the contour around the pole $+i/\sqrt{a}$, I obtain:

$-i \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{{\rm sgn}(x)^2 ~x~ e^{i x}}{1+ax^2} dx=-i ~\frac{2\pi i}{a}~{\rm sgn}\left(i/\sqrt{a}\right)^2~\left(\frac{i}{\sqrt{a}}\right) \frac{\sqrt{a}}{2i}~e^{-1/\sqrt{a}}=-\frac{\pi}{a}~e^{-1/\sqrt{a}}$

where I used: ${\rm sgn}\left(i/\sqrt{a}\right)=i~{\rm sgn}\left(1/\sqrt{a}\right)=i$.

However, I know the correct result (and *Mathematica* agrees) should be just
$-i \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{{\rm sgn}(x)^2 ~x~ e^{i x}}{1+ax^2} dx=\frac{\pi}{c}~e^{-1/\sqrt{a}}$

Why do I pick up the extra minus sign? Am I not applying the residue theorem correctly?

**Note:** this integral is a special case ($n=3$) of the integral I'm actually interested in, namely $-i \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{{\rm sgn}(x)^{n-1} ~x^{n-2}~ e^{i x}}{1+ax^2} dx$

Comment: $\text{}\text{}dp$?

Comment: And $\operatorname{sign}(x)^2 = 1$ almost everywhere, so just forget that.

Comment: @Pragabhava typo, should be $dx$. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielFischer I can forget that in the case $n=3$ (see the note), but not in general... so I want to know why I get different things with and without the sign function

Comment: $\operatorname{sign}$ is not holomorphic, so you can't apply the residue theorem. You have to split the integral (for even $n$) and use symmetries to get something you can apply the residue theorem to.

Comment: @DanielFischer I figured $\operatorname{sign}$ was causing trouble. Could you please explain what you mean by splitting the integral? any suggestions about the symmetries? If you could help me a bit more, I would take that as an answer.

Comment: Also, if $n$ is supposed to be an integer, the integral only exists for $n \in \{2,3\}$, and for $n = 3$ only as an improper Riemann integral (not that that's a problem).

Comment: @DanielFischer is that because of convergence? I am evaluating this as a way to compute: $\int \limits_0^\infty x^{n-2} \sin{(x)}/(1+ax^2) dx$. Did I go the wrong way? (maybe I should create a new question...)

Comment: Yes, the integral doesn't converge for other $n$. $\int_0^\infty x^{n-2}\frac{\sin x}{1+ax^2}\,dx$ also converges for $n = 1$, and you get a principal value integral also for the form in your question when $n = 1$, but for other (integer) values of $n$, you have either a non-integrable singularity in $0$ ($n < 1$) or the oscillations for $x\to\infty$ don't damp out, and the integral doesn't even have a principal value. What is it that you actually need to compute?

Comment: @DanielFischer I see... The idea is to compute something like $\int e^{i{\bf x \cdot y}}/(1+ax^2) d^n {\bf x} \sim \int\limits_0^\infty \left(e^{ixy}-e^{-ixy}\right)/(1+ax^2) x^{n-1} d x$, where ${\bf x, y}$ are n-dimensional vectors. I turned it into an integral over the whole real line to apply the residue theorem, but I guess that doesn't work for even $n$. From what you say, I'm gathering there's no solution to this problem?

Comment: That looks like a Fourier integral. In the denominator, is that supposed to be $\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert^2$? But anyway, you have convergence problems there except for $n = 1$. The thing is square-integrable (or maybe not, depends on what the denominator actually is) for $n \in \{2,3\}$, which is still reasonably good to handle. For larger $n$, it gets difficult. Are you trying to determine the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution?

Comment: @DanielFischer Right $x^2=||{\bf x}||^2$. And, yes: this is essentially a Fourier transform with a modified measure. A colleague of mine got an answer (by writing it as $\int d^n {\bf x} \int\limits_0^\infty ds e^{-s(1+ax^2)}e^{-i{\bf x\cdot y}}$ and using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory#Integrals_with_complex_and_linear_terms_in_multiple_dimensions.), so I don't see why I wouldn't be able to do it this way.

Comment: Well. The integral doesn't exist (except in small dimensions), and that's that. Thus you need to evaluate the Fourier transform in a different way. One way is to evaluate the integral over a ball of radius $R$ and then take the limit $R\to\infty$, if you can evaluate the integral over the ball and the limit exists in the required sense. Another is to multiply the integrand with a decaying function like $e^{-\varepsilon\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert^2}$, evaluate that integral, and take the limit $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ - if you can do that, and the limit exists in the required sense. Or you can do

Comment: what your colleague did (which also requires justification). Or ... - there are many ways that may achieve the goal, but not all ways work in all situations. It looks like transforming it into an integral over the real line and applying the residue theorem doesn't work here. (But there might be a trick that I just don't see.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess my intuition fails at this because I still don't see if one approach works, why don't they all. Where is the loss of information? But in any case, thank you very much, I really appreciate your help. (If you care about those things, I will this as an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a \gt 0$.  Ignore the $\operatorname{sgn}^2{x}$, as that is identically $1$ almost everywhere, except at $x=0$ (which can be ignored as it is measure zero).  Thus you want to find

$$-i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{x \, e^{i x}}{1+a x^2}$$

Then consider the integral

$$-i \oint_C dz \frac{z \, e^{i z}}{1+a z^2}$$

where $C$ is a semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper half plane.  The contour integral is equal to

$$-i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{x \, e^{i x}}{1+a x^2} + R^2 \int_0^{\pi} d\theta\, e^{i 2 \theta} \frac{e^{i R e^{i \theta}}}{1+a R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}}$$

The integral about the semicircle has a magnitude bounded by

$$\frac{2}{a} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-R \sin{\theta}} \le \frac{\pi}{a R}$$

as $R \to \infty$.  The contour integral is also equal to, by the residue theorem, $i 2 \pi$ times the residue of the pole at $z=i/\sqrt{a}$.  Then we have

$$-i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{x \, e^{i x}}{1+a x^2} = i 2 \pi (-i) \frac{ e^{-1/\sqrt{a}}}{2 a} = \frac{\pi}{a} \, e^{-1/\sqrt{a}}$$

Comment: Right, but my question was why do I get a different result when I include the $\operatorname{sign}^2(x)$ part, not how to compute it... The answer seems to be (see comments to the question) that $\operatorname{sign}(x)$ is not holomorphic. Maybe you have some insights about the n-dimensional case (see Note)?

Comment: @misi: to begin, and forgive me, you have a sgn of an imaginary argument, which unless you have some sort of analytic continuation thing going, is rather meaningless/ill-defined. I know you assigned a value to it, but what is that based on, exactly?

Comment: For complex $z$, $\operatorname{sign}(z)=z/|z|$ (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sign.html). Hence, $\operatorname{sign}(i b)=i \operatorname{sign}(b)=i~,~b>0$